# Firestore query - assign repetitive query elements to variable

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

I have many Firestore queries. They differ only with one element. Is it possible to assign repetitive elements to variable?

```
firstQuery = query(productEventsCollection,
                orderBy("created", "desc"),
                where("productEventType", "==", eventType),
                where("created", ">=", startDate),
                where("created", "<=", endDate),
                where("productSKU", "==", prodSku),
                limit(queryLimit));
```

to something like:

```
firstQuery = query(VARIABLE,
                limit(queryLimit));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build an array of function calls that build up your query and then use the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) `...` to call the `query()` function with each item from the array as an argument:

```js
const queryArgs = [productEventsCollection, orderBy("created", "desc"), where("productEventType", "==", eventType), where("created", ">=", startDate), where("created", "<=", endDate), where("productSKU", "==", prodSku)];
const firstQuery = query(...queryArgs, limit(queryLimit));
```